# Determining base URL for GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What is the base url for a GCP Project? I need to specify this for a connector and am not sure what this would be.

Project urls seem to use the project Id for different services such as console, storage, etc thus,

`http://console.cloud.Google.com/home/dashboard?project=<project_id>`

I am looking for the generic URL for the project.

Comment: What do you mean by **base URL** and what is it used for? There isn't a Google Cloud Platform base URL.

Comment: @john-hanley is correct and there is no base URL. However, if you're limiting your interest to Cloud Console, you can use `https://console.cloud.google.com/?project=<project-id>` but this is only for the UI and individual resources are accessible only through further combinations of path and querystring.

Comment: Thank you, this is an attribute in a Google Data Catalog to Collibra integration config file. I will confirm with the publisher and update the post.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following Cloud SDK command may be what you need ([documented here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list)):

```
gcloud projects list --uri
```

It returns a list of projects as URIs. They look like this:

```
https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project-id>
```

I guess you can also try simply inserting your `project-id` in this URI and see if it works.